# The annotated column of one to many mapping is not created in table.Why?

Tags: hibernate

Table of HotelUser...

```
@Entity
public class HotelUser {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue
private int hotelUserId;

@Column
private String hotelUserame;

@Column(name="Role")
@OneToMany(cascade=javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<UserRole> userRole=new HashSet<UserRole>();
.
.
```

I've UserRole table bellow...

```
@Entity
public class UserRole {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue
private int userRoleId;

@Column
private String userRoleName;

//constructor and geter-setter method...
}
```

When I run the project all the column in HotelUser are created but column of UserRole not create, if you give @ManyToOne relationship insted of @OneToMany then it's column create then why not create for @OneToMany mapping...?

Answer (score 0):

OneToMany annotation means One HotelUser will be having Many UserRole this is not possible if column `userRole` is created in `HotelUser` table. It will be one to one mapping.

While when you are annotating ManyToOne which means many users can have one role is justified in DB with having a column in HotelUser table.

In either case I think this is not what you want to achieve. The solution to your problem will be I think going for ManyToMany realtion.